# Kinect v2 from image_color to /dev/video0 -- webcam streaming or other

Tags: ros, kinect, stream, webcam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there everyone. I used ROS quite a bit over summer under a different work account but now that I have learned to love ROS, I want to use it to help me stream RGB video from my Kinect v2 for xBox One. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS Kinetic
I currently have libFreenect2, and iai_kinect2 working, and I can view my published ROS image topics, along with using Protonect and other test programs, but I have not found an elegant way of streaming this video as a linux video device such as /dev/video0

The brutal method I have got working is to roslaunch kinect2_bridge to publish the camera data, use image_view to view the published video in a window, then use ffmpeg with v4l2loopback to stream my entire desktop as the video device.

I have searched long and hard for a better way to do this, and I have had many ideas, but I just cant figure out how to take the image data directly from the camera and push it through as a video device so that I can have that run in the background as I use my desktop. Does anyone have any ideas or know of a better way?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249801/kinect-v2-from-image_color-to-/dev/video0----webcam-streaming-or-other/) by [ateator1](https://answers.ros.org/users/28775/ateator1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2016-12-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See [Can we publish Image topic from ROS to a virtual video device](http://answers.ros.org/question/215325) (via [video from node to v4l2](http://answers.ros.org/question/203812)).

Only fork I can find of the `mayfieldrobotics/ros-virtual-cam` seems to be [lucasw/ros-virtual-cam](https://github.com/lucasw/ros-virtual-cam).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ateator1](https://answers.ros.org/users/28775/ateator1/) on 2016-12-11**:
I don't know how I didnt find that. You rock, thank you! I'll check that out soon and follow up.

**Comment by [ateator1](https://answers.ros.org/users/28775/ateator1/) on 2016-12-11**:
Works almost perfectly out of the box. II can see my /dev/video0 stream on programs like "Cheese Webcam Booth" or "Skype", but not on websites such as http://www.testmycam.net/. That's okay for my purpose, but in case I wanted to fix that issue.. any clues on where to start?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-11**:
Not sure. Could be a `v4l` vs `v4l2` issue. See [Adobe Flash and V4L2 webcams](https://beeznest.wordpress.com/2011/07/02/adobe-flash-and-v4l2-webcams/) fi.

**Comment by [ateator1](https://answers.ros.org/users/28775/ateator1/) on 2016-12-11**:
Your help is appreciated. Thank you